# Using Ubuntu as a Music-Server for iTunes

Tags: server, music, itunes

I fixed together an old Mac Mini Server of the late 2007 series and had to put Ubuntu on it, since I can not install the latest macOS on it. However, that wasn't actually a bad thing, because I am not new to Linux, just to the sole specialties of Ubuntu - so I knew that I could do something great with it.

Currently, I have an estimated volume of 300GB of music in various formats (MP3, WMA, WAV, FLAC...and even OGG) and I would like to centralize them all - to unload my MacBook's internal HD and to keep things well organized.

As you can see though, I need to not just collect all the music (which isn't the hard part), but rather make it available to iTunes as a "Private Share" so that I can pick the songs that I want on the go into my local library - basically, syncing my MacBook instead of an iPhone, just more manually.

I did read about `forked-daap` but couldn't find a clarification if I could have it display all the media found as an "iTunes Private Share" or not. But other than that, I really have no leads.

All I want to do is to centralize my music and pick up which tracks I actually want, and leave the rest on the server to stream it across the network when I am at home. How do I do that?